# In Play 1.2, is there any way to secure a Controller provided by a module without editing module source?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, module, controller, playframework

I'd like to a use a Controller provided in a module but the Controller is not secured. I don't want to edit the source of the module as this will become a maintenance overhead. Does Play offer any kind of solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute-force approach to this is to not include the module's routes (or at least not allow direct access to the controllers you want to secure), and instead allow access to the module only by going through one of your own controllers.  Access control can then be applied in your own controller.

Answer (score 2):

With the Secure-Module you can't do this. I'm working on a module to provide such functionality, but it's not finished, because I have to write more tests and a user management part and some Tags. However if you interested I can send you a link to the repository. It should fit your requirements.

[Deadbolt](http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt) doesn't seems to work too.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I'm very interesting in your module.

Comment: I try to contact you via email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override module controller with your own controller that delegates calls to controller methods with your methods. Supposedly all you have to do is create a controller that extends the module controller you want to secure, add @With(Secure.class) and @Check annotations to it, and change routes to point to that new controller instead of module's controller that it extends.

Look at the example of CRUD module - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.2/guide8

They have Posts controller extending CRUD secured with Secure module. The Posts controller doesn't have any methods of it's own, but effectively inherits those from CRUD (from Play router's point of view):

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

@With(Secure.class)
public class Posts extends CRUD {    
}
```